# How can close PDF file if it is open?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I can create a PDF file with iText library in Java. This works, but now I have this problem, I execute the method, then I have a PDF file, its name is file.pdf and it is ok. Now I re-call the function to create the PDF file, its name is file.pdf but now, if the file is just open, I have an error.

```
FileNotFoundException:Impossible to access at file
```

And is ok this, so I want that if the file is open, from code, close the file then recreate the file and open it.

This is my code to create a PDF file:

```
public static void printFile(String nomeFolder, String nomeFile,List<Articoli> listaArticoli, boolean aprire)throws DocumentException{
    String folderName = DateUtil.getDataGiornaliera();
    nomeFolder = (new StringBuilder()).append(nomeFolder).append(nomeFile+"_"+folderName).append(".pdf").toString();
    File f = new File(nomeFolder);
    try {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), -65F, -65F, 85F, 40F);

        PdfWriter docWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, os);

        EndPageFoglioFatturaFatt hp2 = new EndPageFoglioFatturaFatt(nomeFolder, "Img/ineco1.jpg",folderName);
        docWriter.setPageEvent(hp2);

        FooterDocumenti hp = new FooterDocumenti(nomeFolder, "Img/ineco1.jpg",folderName);
        docWriter.setPageEvent(hp);

        doc.open();

        float[] colonne = {0.7f,1.5f,4.5f,0.5f,0.5f,1.5f,1.5f,1.5f};

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(colonne);
        table.setHeaderRows(1);

        String[] intestazioni = {"C.ART","C.BARRE", "NOME ARTICOLO","IVA(%)", "Q.TA",
                "PR.VENDITA", "ULT.PR.VENDITA", "ULT.DATA ACQUISTO"};
        PdfPCell  cell = new PdfPCell();
        for(int i = 0; i< intestazioni.length; i++){
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(intestazioni[i], FontFactory.getFont("Century Gothic", 8F)));
            cell.setGrayFill(0.9F);
            cell.setUseAscender(true);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(1);
            cell.setVerticalAlignment(5);
            cell.setBorderWidth(0.5F);
            cell.setFixedHeight(15F);
            table.addCell(cell);
        }

        //Vector v = db.eseguiQueryTuttiArticoli("SELECT ARTICOLIDETT.CodArticolo,NomeArticolo,Iva, Quantita,PrezzoAttuale, PrezzoRivenditore, PrezzoIngrosso,  Soglia FROM Articolidett,Articoliquantita WHERE ARTICOLIDETT.CODARTICOLO = ARTICOLIQUANTITA.CODARTICOLO ORDER BY NOMEARTICOLO");
        for (Articoli articoli : listaArticoli) {
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(articoli.getCodArticoloString(), FontFactory.getFont("Century Gothic", 10F)));
            cell.setVerticalAlignment(5);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
            cell.setColspan(0);
            cell.setBorderWidth(0.5F);
            table.addCell(cell);

            ....
            ....
            CODE TO BUILD A FILE
            .....
            .....
        }
        doc.add(table);
        doc.close();
        os.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        log.logStackTrace(e);
        VisualMessageStampe.getErroreFileAperto();
    }
    catch(IOException exp)
    {
        log.logStackTrace(exp);
    }
    catch(DocumentException exp2)
    {
        log.logStackTrace(exp2);
    }

    if(aprire)
    {
        if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
        {
            try
            {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(f.getCanonicalFile());
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                log.logStackTrace(ex);
            }
        } else
        {
            VisualMessageStampe.getErroreAcrobatInesistente();
        }
    }

}
```

How can I fixed my problem?

Comment: When a PDF is open in Adobe Reader, it is locked. You can't overwrite it. Hence you should close `file.pdf` Adobe Reader before you want to create a new PDF with the same name. Why don't you use unique names for the files you save on your file system?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot open an `OutputStream` into a file opened in external application (Adobe Reader or stuff). Some things you could do instead:

- Create new filename for each iteration (creating tempfiles is cheap)
- Check if file exists before you go and overwrite. If exists create a suffix (_1, _2, ...) and check that does not exist.
- Alert user once you see that message to "please close PDF file before creating new"

Something like this might help:

```
protected File getFile(String nomeFile, String nomeFolder) {
      String folderName = DateUtil.getDataGiornaliera();
      nomeFolder = (new StringBuilder()).append(nomeFolder).append(nomeFile+"_"+folderName).append(".pdf").toString();
      File f = new File(nomeFolder);
      int suffix = 1;
      while(f.exists()) {
          nomeFolder = (new StringBuilder()).append(nomeFolder).append(nomeFile+"_"+folderName+"_"+(suffix++)).append(".pdf").toString();
          f = new File(nomeFolder);
      }
      return f;
    }
```